# Flutter Custom Horizontal Slider

Tags: flutter, slider

I want to make a Slider with customized lines with Flutter.

In a section where users choose distance,

It should have lines 0-15-50-500. Is there a way to this?

[image]

Comment: Why not just use [Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html)? If you want to overlay markers, then use a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vm_service/Stack-class.html). Please be more specific about your issue.

Comment: Users can choose the distance to send notifications. But normal users: 0-15,
premium users: 0-50,
There will be a special fee according to the distance between 50-500, which will be valid for everyone. The 0-15-50 stops are important, but then it should increase much faster.

Comment: You are giving requirements for the needs of your app. You need to try to build it with the info you have and then update your question to be more specific about the issues you are having with your code.